# Is it possible to control G1ANT software by itself using ui automation.?

Tags: g1ant

Take will be recursive loop I guess, that's why I haven't tried it so far as it can harm and in worst case even can crash the system...but is there any way through which i can control G1ANT itself through G1ANT.?

Answer (score 1):

To a certain degree, yes.

```
    ui.click ‴/ui[@id='MainForm']/descendant::ui[@name='Minimize']‴
```

command clicks the minimize button of the G1ANT Studio window. So it's possible to automate parts of it. I tried some `keyboard` commands, it didn't work like typing into a `dialog.ask` window for example.